# $injector.instantiate VS $injector.get VS $injector.invoke in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

What are the differences between `$injector.instantiate`, `$injector.get` and `$injector.invoke` in AngularJS?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Given the following service:

```
app.service('myService', function ($q, $http) {
  return {
    q:    $q,
    http: $http
  };
});
```

**$injector.get(name, [caller]);**

Returns an instance of the requested service.

```
$injector.get('myService');
// { q: $q, http: $http }
```

---

**$injector.invoke(fn, [self], [locals]);**

Invokes the supplied method and passes along the given arguments from the $injector.

```
$injector.invoke(function (myService, $http) {
  console.log(myService); // { q: $q, http: $http };
  console.log(this);      // { v: 'im this!' };
  console.log($http);     // null
}, { v: 'im this!' }, { $http: null });
```

---

**$injector.instantiate(Type, [locals]);**

Creates a new instance of the given Type. Takes a constructor function, then invokes the new instance with the arguments specified in the constructor annotation.

Assume the following 'class':

```
function Person (fName, lName, $http, $q) {
  return {
    first_name: fName,
    last_name:  lName,
    http: $http,
    q:    $q
  }
}
```

Now, if we wanted to create a *new* Person in our controller, we could do it like this:

```
app.controller('...', function ($injector) {
  var $http = $injector.get('$http');
  var $q    = $injector.get('$q');
  var p     = new Person('kasper', 'lewau', $http, $q);

  console.log(p); // { first_name: 'kasper', last_name: 'lewau', http: $http, q: $q };
});
```

Imagine `Person` had ~20 or so dependencies, and we were fetching each and every one of them with the `$injector.get` method.

**Cumbersome! And** - you would need to keep your parameters & arguments in sync. *ugh*.

Instead, you can do this:

```
app.controller('...', function ($injector) {
  var p = $injector.instantiate(Person, {
    fName: 'kasper',
    lName: 'lewau'
  });
  console.log(p); // { first_name: 'kasper', last_name: 'lewau', http: $http, q: $q };
});
```

And - if we wanted to, we could supply *locals* to the `.instantiate` call, so as to override what the internal `$injector.get()` would normally get when instantiating.

```
var p = $injector.instantiate(Person, {
  fName: 'kasper',
  lName: 'lewau'
}, { $http: 'Nothing!', $q: 'Nothing!' });
console.log(p); // { first_name: 'kasper', last_name: 'lewau', http: 'Nothing!', q: 'Nothing!' };
```

---

I hope that explains the difference between the three. If you need more information regarding their differences I would recommend these articles:

- http://taoofcode.net/studying-the-angular-injector/
- http://taoofcode.net/studying-the-angular-injector-annotate/
- http://taoofcode.net/studying-the-angular-injector-invoke/
- http://taoofcode.net/studying-the-angular-injector-getservice/
- http://taoofcode.net/studying-the-angular-js-injector-instantiate/

Comment: Did $invoke,get uses $invoke,initialte() and $invoke.invoke()??

Comment: I dont have the source in front of me right this moment, but I think so yes. Check the source friend.

Comment: could you give more example of `injector.invoke` with real use case? Thanks

Comment: Quite the opposite, invoke uses get to fetch dependencies.

Comment: is a new instance created by instantiate destroyed when controller is destroyed too?

Answer (score 0):

Additional marks to Kasper Lewau's answer, because I can't add comments.

**$injector.invoke(fn, [self], [locals], [serviceName]);**

- Can be used for any function: class constructor or not (it has auto-check inside)
- '**Self**' param used only for pure function.

**$injector.instantiate(Type, [locals]);**

- Should be used for class constructors only, or it will construct empty object {}